# increment number in reddit python bot reply

Tags: python, enumeration, praw

I'm trying to make a bot that increments a number every time someone mentions a string. So far I can only get it to increment once and every other reply stays at the same number. It is declared at 2017, but will only reply with 2018 when it finds a string. I know its something small I'm missing but I cant figure it out.

```
for comment in r.subreddit('test').comments(limit = 500):
        mentions = 2017     
        if "string" in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
            mentions +=1
            print ("string found!") and comment.id
            comment.reply(" delayed until year" + str(mentions))
            print("replied to comment")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring `mentions` *inside* the body of the loop, meaning it will be set to `2017` on every iteration.

Also, `print ("string found!") and comment.id` should probably be `print("string found!", comment.id)`.

Comment: ah ok i see I dont know how i missed that. Thanks though that solved it

Comment: If that's all, you might want to accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Declared mentions inside the loop instead of outside, which fixes the issue